# Having different VS Code extension set

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I am using VS Code extensively for different purposes. I am using it for web development, for deep learning with python, and I have my notes in markdown in it. I love the IDE but with all these extensions it gets slow and consumes too much resources of my laptop.

Is there any way to manage three different installs of VS code so that each one has its own set of extensions with related tasks.

Comment: Something like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaronpowell.vscode-profile-switcher?

Comment: I think it is let me test it and come back to you

Comment: It does the trick but I hate it. As it is doing a lousy job of installing and removing all the extensions every time. I think a better way is to preserve different sets of extensions for each account.

Comment: I think it's duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1449639/is-there-a-way-to-install-vs-code-extensions-only-inside-the-workspace . There is a very good answer there too